# Padrão MVC e DAO

Tags: php, mvc, padrão-dao

Tenho um sistema em camadas.

Estou usando o MVC e dentro da pasta MODEL tenho uma pasta DAO.
Vamos supor que tenho um arquivo chamado Professor_DAO e outro chamado 
Aluno_DAO.

Pergunta: Posso incluir o arquivo Aluno em Professor para chamar algum método presente neste? Isso quebraria o padrão?

Comment: Dá uma olhada em ASP Net Razor Pages, que simplifica o MVC

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação?

Comment: @VictorStafusa PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Posso incluir o arquivo Aluno em professor para chamar algum método presente neste? Isso quebraria o padrão?

Pode sim, isso não quebra o padrão MVC. O padrão MVC diz apenas como as camadas de modelo, visão e controlador devem se comunicar. No entanto, `Aluno` e `Professor` são objetos que estão ambos dento da camada de modelo, e portanto o padrão MVC não é quebrado por uma interação entre eles. Aliás, é bastante comum que diversas classes dentro da camada de modelo interajam umas com as outras e não há problema nenhum nisso.

Quanto ao DAO, se você não estiver quebrando a regra de que o `Aluno_DAO` contém métodos de persistência de `Aluno` e que `Professor_DAO` contém os métodos de persistência de `Professor`, tudo bem. É permitido que `Aluno_DAO` possa precisar conhecer algo de `Professor` ou que `Professor_DAO` possa precisar conhecer algo de `Aluno`, desde que um não acabe se preocupando com a persistência do que deveria ser do outro.

Comment: Obrigado pela Resposta!!!